# Replacing Specific Values in a Pandas Column

Tags: pandas

How can I write a loop to replace all values in a pandas column "x" that are 3 to 4? I tried:

```
for i in df['x']:   
  if i == 3:  
     i = 4   
  else:  
     i = i
```

Comment: `df[df['x'] == 3, 'x'] += 1`

Comment: `df['x'].replace({3:4})`